# RSpec validation fails with little explaination

Tags: ruby, mongodb, rspec

I've created an RSpec test to simply test if my model is valid with the given info, it should be, yet my test is still failing.  I'm hoping someone can see why since I've stared at this all day yesterday.

I'm also using MongoDB (not sure if that matters).

**models/stock.rb**

```
class Stock
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :symbol, type: String
  field :last_trade_price, type: Integer
  field :ask, type: Integer
  field :change, type: Integer
  field :change_percent, type: String
  field :market_cap, type: String
  field :avg_volume, type: Integer
  field :change_from_year_high, type: Integer
  field :change_from_year_low, type: Integer
  field :change_from_year_high_percent, type: Integer
  field :change_from_year_low_percent, type: Integer
  field :year_high, type: Integer
  field :year_low, type: Integer
  field :day_high, type: Integer
  field :day_low, type: Integer
  field :day_range, type: String
  field :ebitda, type: String
  field :eps_estimate_current_year, type: Integer
  field :eps_estimate_next_year, type: Integer
  field :eps_estimate_next_quarter, type: Integer


  validates :symbol, :last_trade_price, :ask, :change, :change_percent, :market_cap,
            :avg_volume, :change_from_year_high, :change_from_year_low, :change_from_year_high_percent,
            :change_from_year_low_percent, :year_high, :year_low, :day_high, :day_low, :day_range,
            :ebitda, :eps_estimate_current_year, :eps_estimate_next_year, :eps_estimate_next_quarter, presence: true

  validates :last_trade_price, :ask, :change, :avg_volume,
            :change_from_year_high, :change_from_year_low, :change_from_year_high_percent,
            :change_from_year_low_percent, :year_high, :year_low, :day_high, :day_low,
            :eps_estimate_current_year, :eps_estimate_next_year, :eps_estimate_next_quarter, numericality: true

  validates_uniqueness_of :symbol

end
```

**spec/factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :stock do
    symbol "AAPL"
    last_trade_price 92.51
    ask 92.78
    change -0.91
    change_percent "-0.91 - -0.97"
    market_cap "512.93B"
    avg_volume 37776500
    change_from_year_high -40.46
    change_from_year_low 0.66
    change_from_year_high_percent -30.43
    change_from_year_low_percent 0.72
    year_high 132.97
    year_low 91.85
    day_high 93.57
    day_low 92.46
    day_range "92.46 - 93.57"
    ebitda "82.79B"
    eps_estimate_current_year 8.29
    eps_estimate_next_year 9.15
    eps_estimate_next_quarter 1.67
  end
end
```

**spec/models/stock_spec.rb**

```
describe Stock do
  let(:stock) { build(:stock) }

  it "should be valid if all information is provided" do
    expect(stock).to be_valid
  end
end
```

My output from running the rspec test is:

```
Failures:

  1) Stock should be valid if all information is provided
     Failure/Error: expect(stock).to be_valid
       expected `#<Stock _id: 5734dd60b8066872f6000000, symbol: "AAPL", last_trade_price: 92, ask: 92, change: 0, change_percent: "-0.91 - -0.97", market_cap: "512.93B", avg_volume: 37776500, change_from_year_high: -40, change_from_year_low: 0, change_from_year_high_percent: -30, change_from_year_low_percent: 0, year_high: 132, year_low: 91, day_high: 93, day_low: 92, day_range: "92.46 - 93.57", ebitda: "82.79B", eps_estimate_current_year: 8, eps_estimate_next_year: 9, eps_estimate_next_quarter: 1>.valid?` to return true, got false
     # ./spec/models/stock_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02311 seconds (files took 1.72 seconds to load)
1 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/stock_spec.rb:4 # Stock should be valid if all information is provided

Randomized with seed 36574
```

From looking at the error, it seems that all of the information was built into the factory test object, so I'm unsure why the test is getting `false` instead of the `true` it's expecting.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Snippets are only intended for samples of css/javascript that can be run in the browser. Don't use them for ruby - use the regular indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test what fields are giving an error by modifiying the spec:

```
describe Stock do
  let(:stock) { build(:stock) }

  it "should be valid if all information is provided" do
    #expect(stock).to be_valid
    stock.valid?
    expect(stock.errors.full_messages).to eq []
  end
end
```

However even as such the spec has very little actual value - you're just testing that your factory has all the required fields. If it didn't you would get failures in other specs anyways.

Also if you are grouping a bunch of similar validations by type you might want to use the longhand methods instead as it is much easier to read:

```
  validates_presence_of :symbol, :last_trade_price, :ask, :change, :change_percent, :market_cap,
            :avg_volume, :change_from_year_high, :change_from_year_low, :change_from_year_high_percent,
            :change_from_year_low_percent, :year_high, :year_low, :day_high, :day_low, :day_range,
            :ebitda, :eps_estimate_current_year, :eps_estimate_next_year, :eps_estimate_next_quarter
```

### Added

When defining factories you should use sequences or computed properties to ensure that unique fields are unique - otherwise your validations will fail if you create more than one record from your factory!

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :stock do
    sequence :symbol do |n|
      "TEST-#{n}"
    end
    last_trade_price 92.51
    ask 92.78
    change -0.91
    change_percent "-0.91 - -0.97"
    market_cap "512.93B"
    avg_volume 37776500
    change_from_year_high -40.46
    change_from_year_low 0.66
    change_from_year_high_percent -30.43
    change_from_year_low_percent 0.72
    year_high 132.97
    year_low 91.85
    day_high 93.57
    day_low 92.46
    day_range "92.46 - 93.57"
    ebitda "82.79B"
    eps_estimate_current_year 8.29
    eps_estimate_next_year 9.15
    eps_estimate_next_quarter 1.67
  end
end
```

Gems like [FFaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) are really helpful here. See the [FactoryGirl docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md) for more info.

Also you should use a gem like [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) (Yes it works for mongoid) to clean out your database between specs - the reason your validation is currently failing is that you have residual test state from some other test which is effecting the result.

Comment: I modified the spec to your suggestion, but the failure message is still the same.  Nothing more revealing...

Comment: Did you get one or two failures?

Comment: Then your test suite is configured to fail early - try commenting out  `expect(stock).to be_valid`

Comment: The test passes when commenting that portion out.  So what does that mean?

Comment: @Godzilla74 that you've not called valid.  add `stock.valid?` about the error expectation

Comment: That you need to call valid? on the model first - see my edit

Comment: Ah, now the message says `Symbol is already taken`.  So, is it because I'm using the `let(:stock){}` at the beginning?  Should I just change it to a `before do` ?

Comment: It means that you should be using a sequence for unique attributes in your factory. Edited.